# Why No Cycles in Eric Lippert's Immutable Binary Tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, immutability

I was just looking at Eric Lippert's simple implementation of an [immutable binary tree](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/18/immutability-in-c-part-six-a-simple-binary-tree.aspx), and I have a question about it. After showing the implementation, Eric states that

> Note that another nice feature of
>   immutable data structures is that it
>   is impossible to accidentally (or
>   deliberately!) create a tree which
>   contains a cycle.

It seems that this feature of Eric's implementation does not come from the immutability alone, but also from the fact that the tree is built up from the leaves.  This naturally prevents a node from having any of its ancestors as children.  It seems that if you built the tree in the other direction, you'd introduce the possibility of cycles.

Am I right in my thinking, or does the impossibility of cycles in this case come from the immutability alone?  Considering the source, I wonder whether I'm missing something.

EDIT:  After thinking it over a bit more, it seems that building up from the leaves might be the only way to create an immutable tree.  Am I right?

Comment: Since the data structure is immutable, wouldn't it be impossible for the tree to be created from the other direction, therefore your assumption being equal to Eric's statement?

Comment: Yes, that's what I failed to realize initially.

Comment: Why does everybody assume that a tree node must keep information about its children, rather than about its parent? Is there a definition to that effect somewhere in the article? Seems to me that a tree structure where child nodes point to their parent is a very natural and common way to design things. Not that there's anything wrong with pointing to one's children, but it's not the only way.

Comment: I suppose you're correct in theory, but in practice a tree of that form wouldn't be of much use.  Usually you want to traverse a binary tree starting from the root node, rather than any one of the various leaves.

Comment: @LarsH If you have a tree structure in which the children point to the parents (and that is all), then how do you find all of the children? You will have to keep another list of all of the leaves, at the very least, to be able to traverse the structure. You can't do much useful with a tree in which you only have children pointing to parents.

Comment: @Brian useful != possible. The question was, what is possible?

Comment: @LarsH We're getting into semantics now. I'm not sure you would call that data structure a "tree" or "binary tree"; while it meets the graph-theory definition of tree, it has none of the properties that you usually use a tree for in data structures.

Comment: @Brian, w/o semantics the question couldn't have been asked in the first place. Please give citations about your understanding of tree data structures. You may be right. But see my answer and the real-world example I give there. Getting into what uses are "usual" seems far from the theoretical principle Eric Lippert was describing... which applies to both kinds of tree structures.

Comment: `w/o semantics the question couldn't have been asked in the first place`  Oh, the pedantry!  Make it stop!

Comment: Others have claimed that an upward-pointing tree structure is not useful or not normal. I've shown that it is useful in certain common situations, and is perfectly well accepted as a tree structure. Responding with complaints about semantics and pedantry is a poor substitute for presenting counter arguments or ceding the point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using an immutable data structure, in a strict (as opposed to lazy) language, it's impossible to create a cycle; as you must create the elements in some order, and once an element is created, you cannot mutate it to point at an element created later. So if you created node *n*, and then created node *m* which pointed at *n* (perhaps indirectly), you could never complete the cycle by causing *n* to point at *m* as you are not allowed to mutate *n*, nor anything that *n* already points to.

Yes, you are correct that you can only ever create an immutable tree by building up from the leaves; if you started from the root, you would have to modify the root to point at its children as you create them. Only by starting from the leaves, and creating each node to point to its children, can you construct a tree from immutable nodes.

Comment: @Brian, You could build an immutable tree starting from the root if each node pointed to its parent, instead of pointing to its children. (And each node would have to know if it was its parent's L or R child, in the case of a binary tree.)

Comment: @LarsH I suppose you could do that, but you would never be able to traverse that tree in any useful sort of way.

Comment: @Brian on the contrary... Just keep a separate list of all nodes. (If your list must be immutable, build it up with cons as you go.) Granted you would find top-down traversal inefficient... but sometimes you don't care about that sort of traversal. Real-life example: your leaf nodes are indexed by value, and you need to be able to query their ancestry. Regardless of the application or usefulness, the point is, it's not true that you can only ever create an immutable tree by building up from the leaves. The question was a theory question, and in theory you can.

Comment: +1 for correct 1st paragraph, -1 for incorrect 2nd paragraph (and not amending when correction offered)

Comment: @LarsH I did not amend my answer because the person who asked the question stated in the comments that he was interested only in binary trees which you could traverse from the root, which also happen to be the type discussed in the article linked to. You seem to want me to answer a question different than the one that was asked. Yes, if you read my answer out of context, it is imprecise, but my intent was not for the answer to be read out of context by someone looking for gotchas, but instead to answer the question asked.

Comment: @Brian, I was not looking for gotchas. If one has to read every comment in order to find a context in which your answer could be considered correct, then reading your answer "out of context" is not required in order to find it incorrect. The question originally asked did not specify trees that could be traversed from the root. That was evidently an assumption of yours, and as it turned out later, apparently of the asker - but not necessarily of Lippert. Once an unnoticed assumption is pointed out, you can clarify your question to make it explicit. Or you can leave your answer incorrect.

Comment: @LarsH You don't have to read every comment to find the context. You just need to read the question or the linked article, and apply some common sense. The question is about binary trees, the data structure, not binary trees, the mathematical structure. Sure, you can represent the graph in several ways (as Lippert points out in another answer, you can even represent cycles if you change your representation). The point being made wasn't a deep theoretical point, it was a practical engineering tip about a common data structure and how immutability protects you from a simple kind of mistake.

Comment: @Brian: obviously we differ in interpretation about what "common sense" brings to the question. Also questions of *impossiblity* to me imply a solid theoretical point, not merely a practical tip. You also have not responded to my point that trees represented as I described are practical (not merely a semantic exercise), despite their not being on your radar. But all those differences could be resolved simply by stating in your answer that you're talking about trees represented by parents pointing to children. Then other readers will not have to guess and interpret or be misled.

Comment: @Brian, FYI, I'm content to leave this alone now. I've stated my case.

Comment: @Brian, I concede that as a *binary* tree, it doesn't make as much sense for it to be represented bottom-up. I had not thought about that before. However I don't think that's so obvious that making the top-down assumption explicit is unnecessary, if the question is about a claim that "building up from the leaves might be the only way to create an immutable tree."

Comment: Would there be any particular difficulty defining a language which allowed types to be declared "immutable-leak-safe" even if they passed themselves as leak-safe parameters to the constructors of other immutable-leak-safe types, with the proviso that a constructor which receives such a parameter cannot do anything with it except store it in a field which cannot be accessed until after construction is complete?  I would think one could retain the advantages of a "strict immutability" language (no property that was ever observed could change), while allowing more sophisticated data structures.

Comment: There'd be a few more restrictions than that, but the idea would be that if Foo's constructor passes the new Foo under construction to Bar's constructor, nothing could cause that new Foo to be dereferenced until after Foo's constructor had itself completed.

Answer (score 12):

If you really want to try hard at it you could create a tree with cycles in it that is immutable.  For example, you could define an immutable graph class and then say:

```
Graph g = Graph.Empty
  .AddNode("A")
  .AddNode("B")
  .AddNode("C")
  .AddEdge("A", "B")
  .AddEdge("B", "C")
  .AddEdge("C", "A");
```

And hey, you've got a "tree" with "cycles" in it - because of course you haven't got a tree in the first place, you've got a directed graph.

But with a data type that actually uses a traditional "left and right sub trees" implementation of a binary tree then there is no way to make a cyclic tree (modulo of course sneaky tricks like using reflection or unsafe code.)

Answer (score 2):

When you say "built up from the leaves", I guess you're including the fact that the constructor takes children but never takes a parent.

> It seems that if you built the tree in
>   the other direction, you'd introduce
>   the possibility of cycles.

No, because then you'd have the opposite constraint: the constructor would have to take a parent but never a child. Therefore you can never create a descendant until all its ancestors are created. Therefore no cycles are possible.

> After thinking it over a bit more, it
>   seems that building up from the leaves
>   might be the only way to create an
>   immutable tree. Am I right?

No... see my comments to Brian and ergosys.

For many applications, a tree whose child nodes point to their parents is not very useful. I grant that. If you need to traverse the tree in an order determined by its hierarchy, an upward-pointing tree makes that hard.

However for other applications, that sort of tree is exactly the sort we want. For example, we have a database of articles. Each article can have one or more translations. Each translation can have translations. We create this data structure as a relational database table, where each record has a "foreign key" (pointer) to its parent. None of these records need ever change its pointer to its parent. When a new article or translation is added, the record is created with a pointer to the appropriate parent.

A common use case is to query the table of translations, looking for translations for a particular article, or translations in a particular language. Ah, you say, the table of translations is a mutable data structure.

Sure it is. But it's separate from the tree. We use the (immutable) tree to record the hierarchical relationships, and the mutable table for iteration over the items. In a non-database situation, you could have a hash table pointing to the nodes of the tree. Either way, the tree itself (i.e. the nodes) never get modified.

[Here's another example of this data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601900/t-sql-query-getting-child-nodes-of-a-parent), including how to usefully access the nodes.

My point is that the answer to the OP's question is "yes", I agree with the rest of you, that the prevention of cycles **does** come from immutability alone. While you **can** build a tree in the other direction (top-down), if you do, and it's immutable, it still cannot have cycles.

When you're talking about powerful theoretical guarantees like

> another nice feature of immutable data structures is that 
>   **it is impossible to accidentally (or
>   deliberately!) create a tree which
>   contains a cycle** [emphasis in original]

"such a tree wouldn't be very useful" pales in comparison -- even if it were true.
People create un-useful data structures by accident all the time, let alone creating supposedly-useless ones on purpose. The putative uselessness doesn't protect the program from the pitfalls of cycles in your data structures. A theoretical guarantee does (assuming you really meet the criteria it states).

P.S. one nice feature of upward-pointing trees is that you can guarantee one aspect of the definition of trees that downward-pointing tree data structures (like Eric Lippert's) don't: that every node has at most one parent. (See [David's comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/18/immutability-in-c-part-six-a-simple-binary-tree.aspx) and my response.)

Comment: I see your point, but this doesn't seem like a very useful form for a binary tree.

Comment: @Brian, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29#Tree_representations says "There are many different ways to represent trees; common representations represent the nodes as records allocated on the heap (not to be confused with the heap data structure) with pointers to their children, *their parents*, or both, or as items in an array, with relationships between them determined by their positions in the array (e.g., binary heap)."

Answer (score 1):

You can't build it from the root, it requires you to mutate nodes you already added.

Comment: depends how you design your data structures... If each node has info about its parent instead of vice versa, you can build the tree from the root.

Comment: @LarsH, true that, but it's a perfectly useless tree.

Comment: Not true. See comment to Brian.