# T-SQL Query : Getting Child nodes of a parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following schema :

```
ID , CatID, ParentCatID, SiteID
```

I want to get all the sites that belong to the categories that are the roots ( means their ParentCatID = 0) and all their descendants.

for example :

```
ID , CatID, ParentCatID, SiteID
--------------------------------
1  , 2    , 0          , 3
1  , 4    , 2          , 6
1  , 5    , 4          , 7
```

In this example CatID 2 is the parent of 4 and 4 is the parent of 5.

How can I get all the SiteIDs that belongs to the root category and all its descendants.

Comment: If you want all the descendants of the root object, then how is this different from just getting every record in the table ? Every record is either the root,. or a descendant of the root, no?  Perhaps you left something out of yr description ?

Comment: I am trying to Get all the nodes of for example CatID = 8. and then query another table to get all records where CatID in ( All the nodes)

Comment: How do you make sure that your hierarchy does not have cycles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [recursive Common Table Expression, supported on SQL Server 2005+](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml):

```
WITH hierarchy AS (
  SELECT yt.id, 
         yt.catid,
         yt.parentcatid,
         yt.siteid
    FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
   WHERE yt.parentcatid = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yt.id, 
         yt.catid,
         yt.parentcatid,
         yt.siteid
    FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
    JOIN hierarchy h ON h.catid = yt.catid)
SELECT t.*
  FROM hierarchy t
OPTION (maxrecursion 1000)
```

If you get:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

The default is 100 recursions. The maximum number of recursions can be set via the `maxrecursion` option, up to a maximum of 32767.

Comment: I am getting the following error :


The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: WITH hierarchy AS (
  SELECT yt.id

    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
   WHERE yt.ParentCategoryID = 0 And CultureID = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yt.id

    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
    JOIN hierarchy h ON h.ID = yt.ID)
SELECT ID
  FROM hierarchy t
  OPTION (maxrecursion 1000)

Comment: Fixed.

  
  WITH hierarchy AS (
  SELECT yt.id

    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
   WHERE yt.ParentCategoryID = 0 And CultureID = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yt.id

    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
    JOIN hierarchy h ON h.ID = yt.ParentCategoryID)
SELECT ID
  FROM hierarchy t
  OPTION (maxrecursion 1000)